# Get wrong number of arguments (2 for 0) when running Rspec Test using get and delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

This should be a simple one, but just could not find out why it caused the testing failure. 
I kept getting the following error when running rspec. But after commenting "send" method, everything works fine.

```
  1) Messages GET /messages works! (now write some real specs)
     Failure/Error: get target_app_messages_path(@message.target_app.id)
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (2 for 0)
     # ./app/controllers/messages_controller.rb:37:in `send'
```

routes.rb

```
resources :target_apps do 
  resources :messages do 
    member do
     post 'send'
    end
  end
end
```

Model Code

```
class Message
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :target_app
end
```

Controller Code

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    ...
  end
  def show
    ...
  end

  ...

  def send
    ...
  end
end
```

/spec/requests/message_spec.rb

```
describe "Messages" do
  describe "GET /messages" do

  let(:message) do
    FactoryGirl.create(:message)
  end

  it "works! (now write some real specs)" do
    # Run the generator again with the --webrat flag if you want to use webrat methods/matchers
    get target_app_messages_path(message.target_app.id)
    response.status.should be(200)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 22):

Every object in Ruby has a send method:

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html

By naming your action "send" you caused a name conflict.  Try renaming that action to "sendmessage" or defining it in a different way.  There should be a way to have "send" in your URL map to an action named "sendmessage".

Comment: Another action name to avoid is 'process'.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of things are wrong with this.

The first [is what David Grayson pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8550132/15245). You can't call a method send.

The second, is how you've defined that action in your `config/routes.rb`, it should not be this:

```
resources :messages do
  member 'send'
end
```

As that isn't defining an action at all. In fact, I'm not even sure what that does. It should be this (taking into account you can't call it `send` as well):

```
resources :messages do
  member do
    get 'deliver'
  end
end
```

For more information, see the [Routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

The third thing you're doing wrong is that in your test, you need to reference the action for the controller and not use the route. This is because you're writing a functional controller test that tests a controller.

It should not be this:

```
get target_app_messages_path(message.target_app.id)
```

But rather, this:

```
get :deliver, :id => message.target_app.id
```

The method takes the action as the first argument, parameters as the second argument and session data as the third argument.

Comment: Thanks, Ryan. I tried "get :deliver, :id => message.target_app.id". But it gave me this error "bad argument(expected URI object or URI string)". Any thought? And since I'm using nested resources, how could I pass target_app id to "get" method.

Comment: I can't debug that error without a stacktrace. Could you please gist it?

Comment: Shouldn't it just be `get :deliver, :id => message.id` - why do you need the `target_app.id` when the message already exists and has an id of it's own.

Comment: message is a nested resource in target_apps